# What is [::]:0 address in bitcoin debug.log?

Tags: bitcoind, connection, fallback-nodes, network

I am trying to run and connect multiple nodes on a single machine, i.e different nodes using different ports. I am having trouble in connecting the nodes and making them talk to each other. While debugging, I inserted a `LogPrintf("%s\n",addr)` in the while loop of `ThreadOpenConnections()` in `net.cpp` file.

The output in the debug.log file is always `[::]:0`. What does this address mean ? Is it for localhost representation or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[::]` is IPv6's version of localhost (`0.0.0.0`).

Comment: `[::]` or `[::0]` is 'unspecified', equivalent to v4 `INADDR_ANY = 0.0.0.0`; `[::1]` is the equivalent of `INADDR_LOOPBACK = 127.0.0.1`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Special_addresses

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the correction. `[::]:0` must then mean 0.0.0.0, port 0.